# How do fingerprinting techniques involving Canvas and WebGL work?

Tags: web-browser, fingerprinting

Websites can fingerprint a web browser with techniques involving WebGL and HTML5 Canvas. The website like https://amiunique.org/fp shows an example of this. How exactly do these techniques work? I know they involve the uniqueness of the graphics card. Why would a web browser even expose this information? Since graphics cards are mass produced why do they provide such unique information? Wouldn't two of the same model give the same result?

Comment: The website you link to is actually a PoC from a paper of the same name, which explains it in full.

Comment: Also, [this paper](https://www.ndss-symposium.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ndss2017_02B-3_Cao_paper.pdf) goes into more detail about WebGL that AmIUnique missed.